# Slide up a view and slide down again the same view

Tags: android

I want to make an android app in which I want to implement the same behaviour that available in Inshorts news app. I want to add a view like stack of card and when slide up then will go up and when slide down then the card just now i have slide up should come in front.

Here is my code....

```
public class CardStackViewExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_stack_view);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        MyCardStackView sv = (MyCardStackView)findViewById(R.id.my_stack_view);
        sv.setOrientation(SwipeTouchListener.Orientation.Vertical);
        sv.setAdapter(new CardAdapter());
        View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_page, null);
        sv.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    }
}


public class MyCardStackView extends AbstractCardsStackView {
    private static final String TAG = "MyCardsStackView";

    public MyCardStackView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCardStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCardStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStackGettingEmpty() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stack getting empty");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedLeft() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Swiped Left");
        super.onSwipedLeft();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedRight() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Swiped Right");
        super.onSwipedRight();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Swiped Up");
        super.onSwipedUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedDown() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Swiped Down");
        super.onSwipedDown();
    }
}


public class AbstractCardsStackView extends FrameLayout implements SwipeTouchListener.OnCardMovement {
    private static final int STACK_BUFFER = 5;
    private int index = 0;
    private View emptyStackView = null;
    private boolean emptyPageAdded = false;
    private BaseAdapter adapter;
    private SwipeTouchListener.Orientation orientation = SwipeTouchListener.Orientation.Horizontal;

    public AbstractCardsStackView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AbstractCardsStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AbstractCardsStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        index = 0;
        loadNext();
        appendBottomView();
    }

    public BaseAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public void setOrientation(SwipeTouchListener.Orientation orientation) {
        this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    public void setEmptyView(View view) {
        emptyStackView = view;
    }

    private void loadNext() {
        removeTopView();
        appendBottomView();
    }

    private boolean removeTopView() {
        boolean removed = false;
        int children = getChildCount();
        if ( children > 0 ) {
            View topView = getChildAt(children-1);
            if ( topView != emptyStackView ) {
                removeView(topView);
                removed = true;
            }
            children = getChildCount();
            if ( children > 0 ) {
                topView = getChildAt(children - 1);
                if ( topView.getAlpha() < 0.98f ) {
                    topView.setAlpha(1.0f);
                }
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }

    private boolean appendBottomView() {
        boolean added = false;
        if ( index < adapter.getCount() ) {
            View nextBottomView = adapter.getView(index++, null, this);
            if (nextBottomView != null) {
                nextBottomView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeTouchListener(nextBottomView, this, orientation));
                addView(nextBottomView, 0);
                added = true;
                if (index + STACK_BUFFER > adapter.getCount()) {
                    onStackGettingEmpty();
                }
            }
        } else if ( emptyStackView != null && !emptyPageAdded ) {
            addView(emptyStackView, 0);
            emptyPageAdded = true;
            added = true;
        }
        return added;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedLeft() {
        loadNext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedRight() {
        loadNext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedUp() {
        loadNext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedDown() {
        loadNext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMovedFromCenter(float distance) {
        if ( getChildCount() > 1 ) {
            View bottomView = getChildAt(0);
            float alpha = Math.max(-1.0f, Math.min(1.0f, distance / 300.0f));
            bottomView.setAlpha(Math.abs(alpha));
        }
    }

    public void onStackGettingEmpty() {

    }
}


public class CardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_card, viewGroup, false);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button button= (Button)container.findViewById(R.id.button);
        tv.setText("This is card #" + (i+1));
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tv.setText("You clicked on button #" + (i+1));
            }
        });
        return container;
    }
}

activity_card_stack_view.xml
----------------------------
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CardStackViewExample">

    <com.edcast.cardsctackview.MyCardStackView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/my_stack_view" />

</RelativeLayout>

empty_page.xml
--------------

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="There is no more card"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>


my_card.xml
-----------


<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click on Me"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>


slide_down.xml
--------------

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="500" />
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>

slide_left.xml
--------------

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="500" />
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>

slide_right.xml
---------------

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="500" />
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>

slide_up.xml
------------

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="500" />
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Thanks!

Comment: this feature is available in Inshorts news app.

Comment: I can't upload images. To upload images I should have 10 reputation

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)????

Comment: wait i am uploading...

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/10ql76f.png

Comment: please use the second one, are u able to see the image?

Comment: @JordiCastilla, may i have your email id? I want to send the Android code...

Comment: No, you cant. Post your code here!!

Comment: ok....you can see the video for animation here... http://tinypic.com/r/zlyo91/8

Comment: I have added the code, now you can see the code. Are you able to access the video link.....?

Comment: Anyone can help me on this...? Thanks in advance for answer...

Answer (score 0):

you can do it programmatically using fragment manager and animation but other easy way to do it is use library, [See Library With Code Here](https://github.com/Startappz/DobSliding)

Comment: I think this library is for different purpose. Have you seen the slide up and slide down effect of "inshorts news" android app? I want to implement exactly the same feature.......!